# Spark: Converting WrappedArray of tuples to a string

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe with column that has `array<struct<_1:string,_2:string>>` datatype and following sample data:

> WrappedArray([Book1,Title1],  [Book2,Title2], [Book3,Title3])

I want to convert this column from WrappedArray of tuples to a string

Here is the desired output:

> Book1/Title1 Book2/Title2 Book3/Title3

I tried the following udf passing that column of the dataframe, but it did not work:

```
val unwraparr = udf ((x: mutable.WrappedArray[(String, String)]) => x.map { case (val1, val2) => val1 + "/" + val2 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

(x: Seq[Row]) => x.map { case Row(val1: String, val2: String) => val1 + "/" + val2 })
```

Comment: Is this the complete UDF:     val unwraparr = udf ((x: mutable.WrappedArray[(String, String)]) => x.map { case Row(val1: String, val2: String) => val1 + "/" + val2 })

Comment: Is the way you accepted the input parameters to the udf correct? If there's an array of tuples, do you accept it as `Seq[Row]`?